# How to fetch the Layer States from 2D model (dxf) in ForgeViewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, forge

I have a dxf file that I have uploaded to oss and translated it to svf.

How can I fetch the layer states in my 2D model using forgeviewer?

In autocad, I have these layer states [Screenshot for autocad layer states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFNBj.png).

Namely:

1. F1 Component Plan
2. F2 Electrical Plan
3. F3 Bracket Plan

But when in the forgeviewer, I cant find those lawyer states (Grouping).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this type of information may not be available. Generally, the Forge Model Derivative service always tries to extract a "balanced" amount of information from design files (enough for previewing purposes, but not too much, to make sure the output keeps a reasonable size).

When you load your DXF file into the viewer, you can try querying its metadata using `viewer.model.getData()`, and see if you find the layer state there. I did try that with one of my testing DXFs, and didn't see this information there.

Finally, if you really do need the layer state data, there's another option - you could use [Design Automation for AutoCAD](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/autocad/), with a custom AutoCAD plugin that would extract all the information you need directly from the source file.